# Wicket: How is the better way to use repeated forms using ajax?

Tags: html, ajax, wicket

I have the following classes:

```
public class Group {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    ...
    private List<Person> members;
}

public class Person {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String comments;
}
```

I have the following wicket panel:

```
<wicket:panel>
   <div>
     <!-- Group data -->
   </div>
   <form wicket:id="group">
   <table>
      <tbody wicket:id="container">
         <tr wicket:id="members">
             <td wicket:id="personId"></td>
             <td wicket:id="name"></td>
             <td><input type="text" name="comments" wicket:id="comments" value="" /></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <input type="submit" value="save" >
   </form>      
</wicket:panel>
```

In the other hand, I have a WebPage that have filtering functions and show me the differents groups:

```
<html>
<body>
   <form wicket:id="filterOptions">
     <!-- filter options -->
   </form>
   <div wicket:id="resultingGroups">
       <!-- contains the groups that matching the filters -->
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to update the groups doing ajax submits. I tried using ListView, but, I dont know why, when I click 'save' button the changes are reflected on in the first group panel, if I update any other group and click 'save' the Group object is not updated.

I research a lot and found that ListView is not a good choice for what I want to do, but I don't know which View is the correct one.

Filter form works with ajax button too, and works fine.

I am very new on Wicket.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually ListView, DataView and other repeaters are good for what you want to do.

- the ListView should be populated by a Model with a collection of the items you want

```
    ListModel peopleModel = //... DAO access (database) 
    ListView peopleList = new ListView("resultingGroups", peopleModel){ ... };
```

- in order to repaint (refresh the ListView) you should enclose `peopleList` in a container with the `.setOutputMarkupId(true);` (so that Wicket is able to find that container through ajax).

```
...
    WebMarkupContainer peopleContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("container");
    peopleContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    peopleContainer.add(peopleList);
...
```

- ...and then whenever you want to refresh the results shown in the List you need to set the new results to the model (`peopleModel`) and **repaint the container that has the ListView** (`(*)`)

```
public void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    //... on button click or something
    newPeopleList = // ... DAO
    peopleModel.setObject(newPeopleList);

    target.add(peopleContainer); // (*) repaint
}
```

Hope that helped. More examples here

https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/how-to-repaint-a-listview-via-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

Check https://github.com/vineetsemwal/quickview/wiki